# How can I optimize this jquery script with else statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, menu, navigation

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to write a vertical menu. I have it working at this point so that when you click a list item, it changes the content of a div. The thing is, I know the javascript I've written isn't at all optimized.

If I wanted to add another item to the list, for example, it would require adding in a significant amount of code to the existing script. It would be nice if someone could give me some guidance for using some kind of case/switch or if/else framework that would do the same thing in less code. I tried a few different things but none of them worked like I wanted.

Here's a section of what I have going on now. Divs #2-5 are hidden on load and there is a click function for each list item that individually toggles hide or show for the other divs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#feature2').hide();
$('#feature3').hide();
$('#feature4').hide();
$('#feature5').hide();

$('.feature1').click(function(){ 
$('#feature2').hide();
$('#feature3').hide();
$('#feature4').hide();
$('#feature5').hide();
$('#feature1').show();
});
$('.feature2').click(function(){ 
$('#feature1').hide();
$('#feature3').hide();
$('#feature4').hide();
$('#feature5').hide();
$('#feature2').show();
}); 
etc.
```

Here's the jsFiddle with the code I'm trying to optimize: http://jsfiddle.net/7PTUu/10/

Thanks!

Comment: Did you know you can select multiple elements at once? For example: `$("#features2, #features3, #features4, #features5").hide();`

Comment: Give all of the elements the same class.  Then just do `$('.features').hide();`

Comment: @RocketHazmat And then something like `$(this).show();` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each of your link elements as well as the divs you want to hide/show a common CSS class (e.g., "feature-link", "feature"). Then set the `href` attribute of each link to the ID of the element it's supposed to show or hide. This way you can accomplish all of this with one simple handler.

Example HTML:

```
<!-- in your vertical menu -->
<a class="feature-link" href="#feature1">Feature 1</a>
<a class="feature-link" href="#feature2">Feature 2</a>

<!-- the features you want to show/hide -->
<div class="feature" id="feature1">...</div>
<div class="feature" id="feature2">...</div>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
// Same logic applies to all links.
$(".feature-link").click(function() {

  // Get the feature we want to show.
  var target = $(this).attr("href");

  // Hide all other feature elements
  $(".feature").hide();

  // Show just the one div.
  $(target).show();

  // This is personal preference; I put this here to prevent the ID
  // from being appended to the URL in the browser's address bar.
  return false;
});
```

And [here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6twMM/) to play around with.

Comment: `$(this).show();` makes no sense.  If you clicked on it, it's obviously visible.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yeah, I realized after first posting that I was oversimplifying what the OP was asking. Answer should make sense now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! With advice from all of you, I modified my code (now mostly based off of Dan Tao's answer). Here's the updated jsFiddle if anyone wants to see the implementation. http://jsfiddle.net/7PTUu/15/

Answer (score 3):

Fastest solution (but **not optimal**):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hideDivs() {
        $('#feature1, #feature2, #feature3, #feature4, #feature5').hide();
    }
    hideDivs();

    $('.feature1').click(function(){ 
        hideDivs();
        $('#feature1').show();
    });

    $('.feature2').click(function(){ 
        hideDivs();
        $('#feature2').show();
    }); 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using Dan Tao's solution, but this certainly would have made my code a lot shorter.

Comment: Okay) Dan's solution is really cool, and my is just `code-reducing`)